# How I can create a foreign table using a foreign data wrapper that references to a remote one with the same name?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-data

I have 2 databases one named `logs` that has the table:

```
http_log:
id: serial
method: Varchar(10)
url: varchar(150)
```

I also have an another database named `archiving` that also has a table named `http_log`:

```
http_log:
id: unsinged integer
method: Varchar(10)
url: varchar(150)
```

How I can create the foreign table `archived_http_log` so I can transfer data from the `http_log` to `archived_http_log`. I cannot have a table with the same name in my postgresql therefore I cannot have 2 tables named `http_log`.

What I want top achieve is via a single SQL script to transfer data from `logs.http_log` to `archiving.http_log`. So in a server to run:

```
INSERT INTO archived_http_log VALUES (SELECT * from http_log);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreign table need not have the same name as the remote table:

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE remote_http_log (
   id integer NOT NULL,
   method text,
   url text
) SERVER whatever OPTIONS (table_name 'http_log');
```

Alternatively, you can have two tables with the same name in different schemas.